# Installation of Sharpoint Server

Tags: installation

I have sharepoint server and windows server 2008 R2 x64 environment with me. I googled about installation of sharepoint server in VMWare or VirtualBox. If I go ahead with installation of sharepoint server in VMWare or similar, will that be good to behave as if it was installed on some server that didn't utilize Virtual machine. I mean, would that installation be good to go to utilize server's features?

Let me know if question is not understood!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for performance it'll behave as if installed on the "iron". So it's a great way to evaluate the features.

Another option would be to take a 14 day trial at [cloudshare](http://www.cloudshare.com/), where you can try the different versions.

Comment: Thanks Per for the inputs! So if I need to have Sharepoint Server for good performance, I need to buy a new server with Win Server 2008 R2.Correct?

Comment: That depends on your load. With few users and a small load a single server will be good enough. A virtual machine is a bit slower than the physical, but not much. The part it's hardest to virtualize good is the SQL server. But if there is many users and/or a high load you may need multiple servers.